# Inability to switch to the console using Ctrl+Alt+F1 when Mint freezes

Tags: linux-mint, freeze, adobe-flash

We have two completely different computers both running Mint 17.2, one Xeon server with ECC memory and the other is an i7 laptop with *normal* memory. Both have 8GB of RAM with default swap.

Both are used to play a CPU-demanding Flash Player game (~ 50% of CPU) in the latest Google Chrome with the latest integrated Flash Player.

Both have the recommended kernel installed:

```
$ uname -r
3.16.0-38-generic
```

The problem is, they both freeze almost every day, with an inability to switch to the console using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, so I don't even know what happened.

It could be important that we have AP isolation enabled in our router and SSH is not set-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a couple of computers you can access from one computer to the other (if the system is still running and network) using SSH for instance, that way you may be able to check what happened and kill the process/es you need.

---

From [cas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7696/cas) comment:

> The flash game is probably doing something that is triggering a nasty bug in the video driver or in X.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try switching to another console, using `Ctrl+Alt+F2` for example?

My explanation probably isn't very 'technically accurate' but when you start your Linux, it runs some 'TTY' (a command terminal) that can be accessed via keys combination `Ctrl+Alt+'Function key'` (using keys F1 to F8). If your X server is running on the first console (which is accessed with `Ctrl+Alt+F1`), when you use the key combination you post, you are not changing to other console.

Answer (score 0):

When I've had this issue I've been able to use Ctrl+Alt+Esc to restart X (maybe it just refreshes the display).  Are you by chance running any proprietary Nvidia drivers?  I no longer have freezing issues now that I am not using them on my machine.